# Why do we have a legal tag if legal questions are not welcome?

Tags: discussion, tags

My question "[Can we ship libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll with our installer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303302/can-we-ship-libeay32-dll-and-ssleay32-dll-with-our-installer?noredirect=1#comment633381_303302)" was put on hold.

The legal tag says:

> Questions about legal problems which may arise during software
>   development or questions about software law, patents and copyrights in
>   general.

I do not get why legal questions are discouraged if we have a legal tag (seems to be a contradiction). On the other hand sometimes legal questions seem to be OK ( [Is it against policy here to answer questions of a legal nature unless you're a lawyer?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5741/31438) ). So what is wrong with my question?

Comment: As an aside, you may find that law.se is the right place for your question. They do have tags for crypto and export. And your question is tangentially similar to [What exactly makes encryption a weapon?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3705/what-exactly-makes-encryption-a-weapon).  I *would* be interested to how well that question works on law.se.

Comment: Actually I am located in Germany, the project I`ve been talking about hosted in Europe. I think the crypto weapon thing is mainly a US point of view, but maybe I ask it there. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes, that may very well change things (which is part of the reason that a person answering the question as a programmer may give the very wrong answer and not know it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a big fuzzy gray line between the software licensing questions that we find to be on topic, and the rest of the legal questions.  Many software licensing questions *are* legal questions, that are ones that a programmer is at least somewhat competent to answer as a programmer.  Most legal questions, however as the [more info](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/legal/info) in the [legal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) says:

> The law is a minefield and the best advice anyone can give when asked about legal matters is often:
>
> > ask a lawyer.
>
> Asking legal questions on Stack Exchange is not a substitute for taking proper local legal advice. What we can do is advise whether asking a lawyer is essential or just highly recommended.

We can competently answer some questions. Most often, when the answer is "you need to talk to a lawyer."

With your question, this is something that you need to ask a lawyer. You've gone into the realm of encryption and munitions.  If you are in the US, this gets into [ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) and the like. It is not something that as programmers we are even able to properly give you any correct answer.

You need to talk to a lawyer. This goes ***far*** beyond the legal questions of "can I remove the header from a BSD licensed file?" that are (marginally) on topic here.

Related: [When is a software licensing question on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/40980)